# I am trying to count the number of time a word appears in a .txt file using Python3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to count the number of times a word appears in in a txt file. The program seems to work however I cannot stop it counting what I think is white space (the 60 in my result, which makes no sense as there is more than 60 spaces). Is there a way of stripping - and -- from the middle of words?

```
import string

words = {}

def unique_words2(filename):
    strip = string.whitespace + string.punctuation + string.digits + "\"'"
    for line in open(filename):
        for word in line.lower().split():
            if word == " ":
                continue
            else:
                word = word.strip(strip)
                words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1
    for word in sorted(words):
        print("{0} {1}".format(word, words[word]))

unique_words2("alice.txt")
```

the first 5 results show;

```
 60
a 627
a--i'm 1
a-piece 1
abide 1
```

It is results like 1, 3 and 4 that I would like eliminate.

Comment: What does this have to do with `urllib`? I removed that tag. Also, you could replace unwanted characters using the `re` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `strip` method of a python string only removes specified characters from the beginning and end of the string. Using the `translate` method instead would fix that. (This is the cause of outputs 3 and 4). Output one is caused by a different problem. If a word consisting of entirely characters in `strip` occurs, it gets included in the words dictionary under the empty string.

Tweaked code:

```
import string
def unique_words2(filename):
    words = {}
    strip = string.whitespace + string.punctuation + string.digits + "\"'"
    translation = {ord(bad):None for bad in strip} 
    for line in open(filename):
        for word in line.lower().split():
             word = word.translate(translation)
             if word:
                 words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1
    for word in sorted(words):
        print("{0} {1}".format(word, words[word]))

unique_words2("alice.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks that is a great help!

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html:

```
string.split(s[, sep[, maxsplit]])
```

The words are separated by arbitrary strings of whitespace characters (space, tab, newline, return, formfeed)

Replacing any other separator like '-' with a space should do the trick. No need to take care of repeated spaces since they will be treated as a single space.

```
def unique_words2(filename):
    strip = string.whitespace + string.punctuation + string.digits + "\"'"
    for line in open(filename):
        separators = '-_|'
        for sep in seperators:
            line = line.replace(sep, ' ')

        for word in line.lower().split():
            word = word.strip(strip)
            if word:
                words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1
    for word in sorted(words):
        print("{0} {1}".format(word, words[word]))
```